# Probability for joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x, y) = 2$ for $0 < y < x < 1$.

Find $P(X − Y > z)$.

The answer is supposedly $\frac{(1-z)^2}{2}$ but I couldn't figure out why. I have tried doing the following:

$\int_{0}^{1}  \int_{z+y}^{1} 2 dxdy$

since $x > z + y$ and $1 > x > y$ hence x is bounded by $(z + y) < x < 1$. Then I tried integrating over the interval $[0, 1]$ for y but I'm pretty sure the condition $y < x$ somehow affects the limit of the integral.

Please help, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look to the support.

When $0<Y<X<1$ and $X-Y>z$, then $0<z<X-Y<X<1$ and $0<Y<X-z$  so....

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X-Y>z) &=\mathbf 1_{0<z<1} \int_z^1\int_0^{x-z}2~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{z\leqslant 0}\\[2ex]&=(1-z)^2\mathbf 1_{0< z\leq 1}+\mathbf 1_{z\leq 0} \end{align}$$

Comment: What does the bolded 1_z <= 0 mean here?

Comment: @Fardeem It is an indicator function; a piecewise function that equals one when the indicated condition is true, otherwise equals zero.  $$\begin{align}\mathbf 1_{z\leq 0}&=\begin{cases}1&:&z\leq 0\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\[2ex](1-z)^2\mathbf 1_{0<z\leq 1}+\mathbf 1_{z\leq 0}&=\begin{cases}1&:&z\leq 0\\(1-z)^2&:&0<z\leq 1\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: But the book says the answer is $\frac{(1-z)^2}{2}$. Are you sure this is the answer?

Comment: Yes, quite sure. @Fardeem

Comment: @Fardeem  To be sure, check that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\mathsf P(X-Y>h) = 1$ as it should.